# Как преобразовать дату в определенный формат?

Tags: c#

Есть текущая дата. Как его преобразовать в формат

```
Thirsday 14th December 2017
```

Текущий вариант такой

```
var dayofweek =  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[(int) 
            System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek];

var month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
var date = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
var year = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();


return dayofweek+" " +date+"," +month+" "+year;
```

Понимаю что пахнет индусским кодом, но все таки) Как сделать проще

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine (now.ToString("dddd d MMMM yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-GB")));
```

Вывод: `Thursday 14 December 2017`

Подробнее на [metanit.com](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/19.2.php)

Comment: Думаю ссылку лучше дать на [docs.mirosoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) или msdn, как на офф. источник

Comment: @Vladislav Khapin нельзя давать ссылки на msdn. Гляньте на табличку с функциями-членами https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9xd04bzs.aspx

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов: Почему нельзя давать ссылки на msdn? Ну в одной статье ошиблись в переводе, ну так давайте ссылку на английский контент, он в порядке.

Comment: @VladD, ИМХО, Microsoft давно уже потерял контроль на документацией. Я быстрее нахожу ответ на StackOverflow, чем в MSDN. Ну и хорошо бы, на странице MSDN, где они спрашивают была ли она полезна, в данном конкретном случае сказать нет, с описанием проблемы. Может это заставит их почесаться.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов: А вы думаете, те, кто даёт ответ на SO, где находит информацию? :-P

Comment: @VladD таинство магии издревле передается изустно, ибо живое знания не отделимо от мага, которому лень писать документацию, без принуждения со стороны главного мага, отвечающего за prodaction. И Microsoft не исключение из этого правила.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов: Тем не менее, такой гримуар как MSDN хорошо помогает непосвящённым вроде меня.

Comment: @VladD "...непосвящённым вроде меня.." чет-то ржу". Боюсь, что нас с Вами сейчас погонят за флуд, однако я бы пнул еще раз службу поддержки Microsoft https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9xd04bzs.aspx . Хуже от от этого не будет, а польза может произойти может несомненная.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов: Ну Microsoft всё равно переносит документацию сюда: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/standard-library/vector. Там пока перевода нет, так что всё правильно.

Comment: @VladD, безусловно Вы правы, однако первым в выдаче  https://yandex.ru/search/?lr=213&clid=2051430&win=124&msid=1513248073.74665.22863.29694&text=c%2B%2B%20vector стоит ссылка на критикуемый ресурс.

Comment: Что касается ответа, то вот это не учтено CultureInfo("en-GB")